# Is there a better way to do this than using an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

I am trying to create a template for forms that checks for a `data-regex` custom param on an HTML element and then creates a regular expression from it to be used to validate the input. Here is what I have so far.

```js
var textInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form__text");
for (var i = 0; i < textInputs.length; ++i) {
  if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "email") {
    (function() {
      var pattern = /.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*@.*\.[a-zA-Z]+/;
      textInputs[i]
        .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
        .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          checkText(pattern, e);
        });
    })();
  } else if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "text") {
    (function() {
      var patternStr = textInputs[i].getAttribute("data-regex");
      var pattern = patternStr ? new RegExp(patternStr) : null;
      textInputs[i]
        .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
        .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          checkText(pattern, e);
        });
    })();  
  }
}

function checkText(pattern, e) {
  if (pattern && e.target.value.search(pattern) == -1) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.add("form__text--error");
  } else {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("form__text--error");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px;
}
.form .form__text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem 0;
  display: block;
}
.form .form__text__label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.form .form__text__error-label {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text], .form .form__text input[type=email] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=text]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label {
  transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(-125%) scale(0.75);
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(122, 217, 255, 0.075);
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__label {
  color: red;
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__error-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text], .form .form__text--error input[type=email] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text--error input[type=email]:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Email</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Email</label>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text" data-regex="[a-zA-z ]{4,}">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Name</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Name</span>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="text" id="random" name="random" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Random Fact</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

I had to wrap the two `addEventListener` blocks inside IIFE's because if not, the pattern variable would be overwritten whenever the callback was triggered. I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to do this. I'm assuming that there is some expense to creating the regex objects, which is why I was trying to create them once outside of the callbacks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need an IIFE for the first one. You have the same pattern `var pattern = /.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*@.*\.[a-zA-Z]+/;` every time, so it doesn't really need to be captured in a closure.

Comment: Does this need to be ES5 only? Because with ES6 the solution is to just use `let` or `const` for `pattern. But if you need an ES5 solution, there are probably other ways.

Comment: tldr; Too long / Not a minimal example / Didn’t read. SO is not a code-review site, although there is one for that..

Comment: @user2864740 The JavaScript is the only thing that is relevant. I added everything else to make it easy to sandbox.

Comment: It’s not a relevant SSCCE or focused question, even if only the JS was present.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize that the email block was still working. However, I'm confused as to why this one never gets overwritten, but the other one does. Is it because it is in it's own if block?

Comment: @AdamJohnston well, it it *would* be overwritten...with the same regex. So it doesn't really matter in that case.

Comment: I did. Would have been happy to not have a notification starting the “argument”.

Comment: @VLAZ, but it doesn't get overwritten by the text fields because it's in a separate if block?

Comment: @AdamJohnston wait, you're right. I missed that. In my defence, I'm just drinking my coffee, now...

Comment: @VLAZ Haha, no problem. I'm just confused because I'm used to C where these variables would all just go out of scope immediately. But what you said made me realize I'm being stupid and I can just create a separate emailPattern variable outside the loop and pass that in. So either way I can at least get rid of the IIFE there. But I'll look into ES6. I wasn't planning on doing a whole lot of JS for this project so I was trying to keep it minimalistic. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pattern` will be a shared variable name for the entire function. Then later when the event listener fires, it will pick up whatever is the last version of `pattern` rather than the current one. It's [a classic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

## ES6 solution

With the introduction of [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) you can have variables in block scope, so the solution is dead simple - change any `var` to either `let` or `const`.

```js
const textInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form__text");
for (let i = 0; i < textInputs.length; ++i) {
  if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "email") {
    const pattern = /.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*@.*\.[a-zA-Z]+/;
    textInputs[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        checkText(pattern, e);
      });
  } else if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "text") {
    const patternStr = textInputs[i].getAttribute("data-regex");
    const pattern = patternStr ? new RegExp(patternStr) : null;
    textInputs[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        checkText(pattern, e);
      });
  }
}

function checkText(pattern, e) {
  if (pattern && e.target.value.search(pattern) == -1) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.add("form__text--error");
  } else {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("form__text--error");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px;
}
.form .form__text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem 0;
  display: block;
}
.form .form__text__label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.form .form__text__error-label {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text], .form .form__text input[type=email] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=text]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label {
  transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(-125%) scale(0.75);
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(122, 217, 255, 0.075);
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__label {
  color: red;
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__error-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text], .form .form__text--error input[type=email] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text--error input[type=email]:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Email</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Email</label>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text" data-regex="[a-zA-z ]{4,}">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Name</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Name</span>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="text" id="random" name="random" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Random Fact</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

You can use Babel to transpile your code from ES6+ to ES5, so you'd write the above but it will be automatically tranfformed to older code that works the same as the new one.

**NOTE:** `let` and `const` will be accepted by IE11 *however*, they will behave exactly the same as `var`. IE11 only makes them allowed syntax but as aliases to `var`. They wouldn't be block scoped.

## ES5 solution

If you have to use ES5 then it's not that big of a problem. The trouble is lack of block scopes, there are only global and functional scopes. So, you'd need to capture the variable inside a functional scope. An IIFE does that but it looks a bit ugly.

### Curry `checkText()`

We can instead make `checkText` a higher order function that is [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) - instead of taking two parameters, it takes one parameter first, then returns a function that takes a second parameter. This looks like this:

```js
function checkText(pattern){
  return function(e) {
    if (pattern && e.target.value.search(pattern) == -1) {
      e.target.parentElement.classList.add("form__text--error");
    } else {
      e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("form__text--error");
    }
  }
}
```

It is a powerful construct here, since it allows us to immediately capture a variable if we call `var returnedFunction = checkText(pattern)` - now even if the variable pattern changes in the enclosing context, `returnedFunction` will still hold the previous one.

### Replace the old call

As a bonus, this allows us to eliminate some useless code. Let's walk step by step for complete understanding - first this

```js
.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  checkText(pattern, e);
});
```

has to turn into

```js
.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var returnedFunction = checkText(pattern);
  returnedFunction(e);
});
```

because we have to pass the parameters into two different functions now. **There is still the same problem as before at this point**. Right now this doesn't solve anything but I want to show the intervening step. Same issue - when the listener fires, *then* `checkText(pattern)` will be executed at which point `pattern` is already changed.

### Make sure `checkText(pattern)` captures the correct value

We need to make sure it fires *before* being initialised in the event listener:

```js
var pattern = patternStr ? new RegExp(patternStr) : null;
var returnedFunction = checkText(pattern);
/* ...code... */
.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  returnedFunction(e);
});
```

When we place it at the same level as the `pattern` variable, so just outside the `.addEventListener` callback, it works as intended without using an IIFE. We would capture the *current* pattern variable and changes to it will not affect `returnedFunction`.

### Simplifying the abstraction

However, the callback function now is this `function(e) { returnedFunction(e); }` - a function that takes a parameter and calls a function that passing the same parameter as an argument. Calling `<anonymous function>(e)` is *the same* as calling `returneFunction(e)`. The outer wrapper function and the inner `returneFunction` have the exact same signature and the semantics of calling them with a single argument are virtually the same. Thus, the wrapper is useless now. We can remove it and perform what lambda calculus calls Eta reduction to simplify the abstraction, thus the whole callback becomes

```js
var pattern = patternStr ? new RegExp(patternStr) : null;
var returnedFunction = checkText(pattern);
/* ...code... */
.addEventListener("input", returnedFunction);
```

Now the event listener is just `returnedFunction`. When it is fired, it will be passed the same argument as before.

### Remove the extra variable

Finally, the last step in the simplification is to just inline the `checkText(pattern)` call. We don't really need the extra variable here. It's easy to just get rid of it and have

```js
.addEventListener("input", checkText(pattern));
```

Done. This was detailed because I wanted to show the process. In practice, it's just converting the `checkText()` function to a curried variant and then replacing the callback with it. Hopefully, the steps turn it from some weird instructions that happen to work into understanding why that's being done.

The final result is this:

```js
var textInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form__text");
for (var i = 0; i < textInputs.length; ++i) {
  if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "email") {
    var pattern = /.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*@.*\.[a-zA-Z]+/;
    textInputs[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", checkText(pattern));
  } else if (textInputs[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "text") {
    var patternStr = textInputs[i].getAttribute("data-regex");
    var pattern = patternStr ? new RegExp(patternStr) : null;
    textInputs[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", checkText(pattern));
  }
}

function checkText(pattern){
  return function(e) {
    if (pattern && e.target.value.search(pattern) == -1) {
      e.target.parentElement.classList.add("form__text--error");
    } else {
      e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("form__text--error");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px;
}
.form .form__text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem 0;
  display: block;
}
.form .form__text__label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.form .form__text__error-label {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text], .form .form__text input[type=email] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=text]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus ~ .form__text__label, .form .form__text input[type=email]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__text__label {
  transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(-125%) scale(0.75);
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text input[type=email]:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(122, 217, 255, 0.075);
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__label {
  color: red;
}
.form .form__text--error .form__text__error-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text], .form .form__text--error input[type=email] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.form .form__text--error input[type=text]:focus, .form .form__text--error input[type=email]:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Email</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Email</label>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text" data-regex="[a-zA-z ]{4,}">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Name</span>
    <span class="form__text__error-label">Invalid Name</span>
  </label>
  <label class="form__text">
    <input type="text" id="random" name="random" placeholder=" " />
    <span class="form__text__label">Random Fact</span>
  </label>
</form>
```